# SAMD21 Xplained pro + Arduino IDE

Tags: samd21

How can I install board files into the Arduino IDE in order to upload my code to the ATSAMD21 Xplained Pro evaluation board. Can I know how can I do it? I Googled it but I didn't get any correct solution.

Comment: Were you able to figures this out?

Comment: Nope david. I wasn't able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you want:

https://github.com/AtmelUniversityFrance/atmel-samd21-xpro-boardmanagermodule/wiki

Disclaimer: I've not tried this out yet (but I'm about to...)

Update: I followed the directions there and it worked.